# The logic behind location string in HTML

Tags: html

In HTML, there are in many pages links which point to a sub-directory, let us consider

```
href="Dir/Subdir/Subdir2/index.html"
```

On some pages, however, links in a file in a subdirectory point to a different subdirectory at the same level, in a matter as if it was in a relative subdirectory. In other words,

```
Dir/Subdir/Subdir2/index.html
```

would contain

```
a href="Subdir/Subdir3333/index.html"
```

which would in fact point to

```
Dir/Subdir/Subdir3333/index.html.
```

I would think this was wrong, however conventional browsers point to the correct locations.
I have been looking for a solution for quite a while now, though I couldn't find an answer.

Could you point me to a specific part of HTML documentation which explains how the relative locations work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a base href attribute in your HTML document's head which makes all relative URLs start at this BASE url.

See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp).

Otherwise the relative paths work the same as filesystem paths. / to the root (domain) and ../ to go up one directory.

Answer (score 0):

Extract from [W3 specification:](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-BASE)

> User agents must calculate the base URI for resolving relative URIs according to [RFC1808], section 3. The following describes how [RFC1808] applies specifically to HTML.
>
> User agents must calculate the base URI according to the following
> precedences (highest priority to lowest):
>
> - The base URI is set by the BASE element.
> - The base URI is given by meta data discovered during a protocol
>   interaction, such as an HTTP header (see [RFC2616]).
> - By default, the base URI is that of the current document. Not all
>   HTML documents have a base URI (e.g., a valid HTML document may
>   appear in an email and may not be designated by a URI). Such HTML
>   documents are considered erroneous if they contain relative URIs and
>   rely on a default base URI.